# Nuxt Sass/Scss @imports inside imported node_modules

Tags: sass, node-modules, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use the Sass parts of [Material design](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) official library inside my Nuxt project.

I have created a file inside assets folder called `styles.scss` and tried to import a simple component like this :

```
@import "~@material/textfield/icon/mdc-text-field-icon";
```

However it's displaying me this error :

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import "@material/theme/variables";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: @material/theme/variables.
```

Obviously it's because there is no `~` inside the import name so Nuxt doesn't know where to find it...

Does anyone know how i can solve this ? With node-sass, i used the `--include-path` to solve this issue but i didn't found anything similar in nuxt...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to solve my problem by adding the following code to `nuxt.config.js` :

```
build: {
  extend(config, context) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          includePaths: ["./node_modules"]
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but i don't need any `~` inside my scss, it automatically search inside the node_modules, which is nice.